# jQuery's load() doesn't display images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

Good evening everyone,

I am using a JavaScript to load/override content from an HTML-File into specified divs.
You can [watch a demo](http://www.yachtfinder-app.com/jload/).

The javascript that does the load job looks like the following:

```
function loadScreenie(elementSelector, sourceURL) {
    $(""+elementSelector+"").load("img/screenies/"+sourceURL+"");
}
```

and gets invoked by a hyperlink looking like this:

```
<a href="javascript:loadScreenie('#iphone-screen', 'screenie2.htm');">mibmib</a>
```

( i have also tried the same with onclick="")

This is the content of screenie2.htm

```
hello world<br />
<img src="screenie2.png" />
```

The problem is that **images are not displayed.** The behaviour is like this:
- you click the link and the javascript is executed.
- the text in screenie2.htm is displayed correctly in the correct div
- the image is *not* displayed. there also isnt any broken image symbol or an empty space.

Do you have an idea what could cause this error?

Thanks a lot in advance,
-- benny

Comment: I saw the images fine... Assuming that on your demo page I click the only possible link there.

Comment: yep - the image `<img src="bt_close.png"/>` appears for me too

Comment: Problem is that the demo loads everything from the same directory. His problem however states that the document is loaded from a subdir.

Comment: of course the images on the demo appeared fine, but not on the actual page i want to use the script on. the demo was just to show how it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Let me conclude to you what is happening here.

1. When link is clicked, jQuery loads "img/screenies/screenie2.htm
2. The image-tag `<img src="screenie2.png" />` is inserted into the DOM.

So, we have an image linking to a supposed image at *./screenie2.png*, where you would believe it should be linking to *./**img/screenies/**screenie2.png*.

You need to use absolute URLs in your `load()`:ed content.

Comment: Yup, try the absolute URL that MC talked about...sounds about right.

Comment: this works, thanks a lot! i also made my file structure a bit simplier as this is quite complicated :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing with IE, the problem might be that Jquery uses innerHTML instead of creating individual dom elements with the load command.  IE can be very finicky about that.

Comment: i was testing with FF, Safari and Chrome, all the latest versions.